# Is there a way to SELECT a database table using a variable?

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

I tried this statement:

`string query = "SELECT question FROM '" + GlobalVariables.dbQCode + "' WHERE [question_code] = '" + GlobalVariables.questionCode + "' ";`

and when I run the code it is giving me an exception:

*Syntax error in query. Incomplete query clause.*

Is there a way where I can use my variable? I want it to work because I want this code to work also:

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "General Education"){
                GlobalVariables.subjectCode = "GenEd_English";
                GlobalVariables.dbQCode = "Gen_Ed_Question_Items";
                GlobalVariables.dbCCode = "Gen_Ed_Choice_Bank";
                if (comboBox2.Text == "English")
                {
                    GlobalVariables.subjectName = "ENGLISH";
                }
                
}
```

Comment: [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection) • [SqlCommand Parameters Add vs. AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110001/sqlcommand-parameters-add-vs-addwithvalue)

Comment: `FROM " + GlobalVariables.dbQCode + " WHERE` or `FROM [" + GlobalVariables.dbQCode + "]`?

Comment: oh yes that worked, thank you very much, I'm sorry I'm new to SQL statements. Thank you!

Comment: @tenkyu especially when you are new, it's _very_ important you carefully read Oliviers links. better learn _now_ how to do it right, than to debug security holes some years later.

Comment: @OlivierRogier - first comment how to prevent SQL injection, second comment here code which is open for sql injection

Comment: @RandRandom SQL parameters can't be used for table names, as I know: [SqlParameter does not allows Table name - other options without sql injection attack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947736/sqlparameter-does-not-allows-table-name-other-options-without-sql-injection-at) and [Table name and table field on SqlParameter C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128582/table-name-and-table-field-on-sqlparameter-c)

Comment: I really wonder if such a concatenation is the best way of solving the problem. Why are you trying to select from tables dynamically?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and the links you've provided, I will read all that, I thank  you guys very much. However, this is just for a small school activity. But I really appreciate your concern about my codes, thank you!

Comment: @tenkyu Always use SQL *typed* parameters, don't start with a bad habit.

Comment: @Alejandro, our teacher gave us different tables for Questions and Choices with different subtopics, which is weird but I tried to use an if-else so I don't have write to the code repeatedly

Comment: @OlivierRogier, I'll take note of that sir, thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes (`'`) denote string literals. Object names, such as table names, should **not** be surrounded by quotes:

```
string query = "SELECT question FROM " + GlobalVariables.dbQCode + " WHERE [question_code] = '" + GlobalVariables.questionCode + "' ";
// Quotes removed here --------------^-----------------------------^
```